How to insert a Horizontal Scrollbar in a Tkinter Frame with multiple Entry Columns?
I have the following code:
from tkinter import *

Main = Tk()
# Main window
Main.title("Program")
Main.geometry("900x520")
# Background photo placed on top of Main
Photo_BG = PhotoImage(file=r"..//\Pictures\Background2.png")
Background_Main = Canvas(Main, width=800, height=400)
Background_Main.place(x=1, y=1)
# Frame One placed on top of Background photo. Frame One will be used to place widgets on it
Frame_BG = PhotoImage(file=r"..//\Pictures\Frame.png")
Frame_one = Frame(Background_Main, width=300, height=200)
Frame_one.place(x=1, y=1)
Label_Frame_one = Label(Frame_one, image = Frame_BG)
Label_Frame_one.place(x=1, y=1)
# Horizontal Scrollbar for the Frame One to Scroll Entry Columns
hbar = Scrollbar(Frame_one,orient = 'horizontal',width= 20)

for i in range(9): # columns
    for j in range(4): # rows
        entry_grid = Entry(Frame_one, width=7, fg='black', font=('Arial',10,'bold'))
        entry_grid.place(x=((i*60)+1), y=((j*20)+1))
        entry_grid.insert(END, str(i+j))
        entry_grid.config(state= "disabled")
        
entry_grid.config(xscrollcommand = hbar.set)
hbar.place(x=1, y=90)
Main.mainloop()

And this is the output:

How do I manage to scroll horizontally between columns only in the Frame_One? I want to use the place proprieties, not the pack.

You can't scroll the contents of a frame. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter/3092341#3092341

I edited my question. Can you please check?

.place() has width and height options.

It is better to post your update as answer and accept it to close the question.

Based on this link and help from comments I managed to find what I was searching for.
from tkinter import * 

def onFrameConfigure(event):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    Background_Main.configure(scrollregion=Background_Main.bbox("all"))

# Creating Main Window
Main = Tk() #<----- usually instead of "Main" notation it is "root"
Main.geometry("500x400")
Main.title("Program")
# Loading Background Photo
Photo_BG = PhotoImage(file=r"..//\Pictures\Frame.png")
# Loading Canvas on top on Main window
Background_Main = Canvas(Main, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff", width=400, height=300)
Background_Main.create_image(0,0,image=Photo_BG, anchor='nw')
Background_Main.place(x=0, y=0)
# Creating Frame_one on top of Background_Main
Frame_one = Frame(Background_Main, background="#ffffff")
# Creating horizontal and a vertical Scrollbar on top of Background_Main
vsb = Scrollbar(Background_Main, orient="vertical", command=Background_Main.yview)
hsb = Scrollbar(Background_Main, orient="horizontal", command=Background_Main.xview)
# Populate Grid Entry with fake data
for i in range(33): # columns
    for j in range(33): # rows
        entry_grid = Entry(Frame_one, width=7, fg='black', font=('Arial',10,'bold'))
        entry_grid.grid(row=j, column=i)
        entry_grid.insert(END, "N/A")
# Configuring  scrollbar commands
Background_Main.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
Background_Main.configure(xscrollcommand=vsb.set)
# Placing the Scrollbars on the Background_Main
vsb.place(x=0, y=0, height=300, width=20)  #<----- height and width option can resize scrollbar
hsb.place(x=20, y=0, height=20, width=380) #<----- height and width option can resize scrollbar 
# Creating an editable window on top of Background_Main
Background_Main.create_window((20,20), window=Frame_one, anchor="nw",
                       tags="Frame_one")

Frame_one.bind("<Configure>", onFrameConfigure)

Main.mainloop()


